# Guitar rig settings to get a deathcore sound on guitar

Tags: software, amplifier, guitar, distortion, metal

I am trying to make a deathcore sound on guitar rig software for guitar but cannot find something decent.
I tried downloading some presets but either they weren't good enough or they were not compatible with my version of guitar rig.

The settings that gave me the best sound so far were the following.
Skreamer with very little gain and tone almost in the middle, eq decrease mids and amp 51 modern 4x12 but they aren't good enough.
Note that I am not a producer and my experience with eq is minimal.

Can you suggest some settings for guitar rig 5, that give a good sound that sounds similar to the band "thy art is murder"?

Comment: Amp sounds are greatly dependant on input. You're not going to get death metal out of a strat, or any low output single-coil setup. Interaction with the magnets of the pickups & your playing/damping technique are also considerable factors. Perhaps if we knew the rest of your setup, we may have more idea…

Comment: Well I don't know anything about magnets and how they affect the signal. I can just mention the guitar I use. It's an esp LTD guitar, and sounds awesome on physical amps, the problem is that I cannot make it sound good with guitar rig 5.

Answer (score 1):

You are off to a good start, but you need more. A death metal set up I occasionally use (can't remember where I got it from originally) is as follows:

- Compressor - Volume about 1/2, Sustain about 1/3
- Skreamer - Volume 1/2, Tone 3/4, Drive 3/4
- Gain Booster - Boost 1/3
- Custom EQ - Tone 1/2, Freq almost 0, Scoop at max, Volume 1/2
- Equalizer Shelving - A general rolloff as freq increases

Start with that and play - should be useful.